# Jquery dialog box, changing the text field size and font

Tags: jquery, css, dialog

I'm writing a Canvas game in HTML 5 and i want to float a div over the canvas so the user can enter their name into a box and the game capture it.

I've got this working but i have no idea how to actually change the size of the text, font  and length of the box the user types in.

My JS is as follows:

```
$("#menuBox").dialog({
    resizable : false,
    position  : [30,30],
    minHeight : 100,
    minWidth  : 10,
    height    : 200,
    width     : 500
});
```

In the body

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
  <div id="menuBox" style="display:none">
    <form action="POST"> <input type="text" /></form>
  </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

and the CSS

```
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}

#container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-image: url("Main.jpg");
  height: 540px;
  width: 900px;
}

div.ui-dialog div.ui-widget-header { 
  border: none; 
  display: none;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content  { 
   border: none; 
   padding: 0;
}

.ui-dialog {
   width: 500px;
   padding: 0;
}
```

So the idea is the only thing the user sees is the long text box and it just appears over my formatted canvas environment.

I'm new to JQuery (which is why the first bits are still non-JQuery), so i'm not even sure what i want is possible. If I wanted to make the font size 20 and Tomoha and the input box 300px long, i can't see where i would enter this or even if i could make it happen, as using the parameters in .dialog doesn't seem to alter that input field. Any advice?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If problem is only updating styles for dialog box content, you can mention specific parent ID or class like below.

If this didn't solve, it would be better to provide quick solution if you can show me the dialog box html code generated by jQuery.

```
#menuBox .ui-dialog-content {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Tomoha;   
}
#menuBox .ui-dialog-content input {
    max-width: 320px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, i didn't realise you can add input to the end of .ui-dialog-content > Once i'd done that and set all the attributes i can do whatever i want to it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

did you tryed something like  :

```
$(some_element).css({'width':'','font-size':''});
```

?

or by css: you need to use `!important` to ovveride rules, ie:

```
.dialog{
width:300px !important;
}
```

Comment: yes, both on it's own like that and added as a .css on the end of the initial dialog call. I'm not sure if you can actually modify the "white box" at all where the user inputs text.

Comment: how the user submits the text? can you show some code or jsfiddle?

Comment: ok, i'm really confused now. I've knocked up a quick example in jsfiddle and it works there, but the code doesn't on my larger program, but it's line for line the same! http://jsfiddle.net/KhhH4/28/

Comment: do you use the $(document).ready(); ? do some order in your js and all will works fine i think

Comment: No, but setting the content input as shown below has solved this. Thanks for looking through it for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Generic answer: use your browser's DOM inspector feature to visualize the dialog's structure, then use this knowledge to build the required CSS selectors.
I recommend looking at [w3schools CSS selector reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).